# using array strings in an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, int

I am trying to work out how to add a value to a variable based on if a String is present in an array. Hopefully my code will explain it better:

```
//calculate bonus
String[] department = {"Dublin","London","London","Dublin","Paris","Paris"};
int [] brokerTotal =(79,35,55,101,63,108};

int[] bonus;
bonus=new int[6];

for(int i = 0;i < department.length; i++) {
    if (department ="Dublin") bonusRate=12;
    else if (department="London") bonusRate=15;
    else bonusRate=10;
    bonus[i] = ((brokerTotal[i])/100)*bonusRate;
}
```

The if statements are catching me here, am I close or totally off the mark here?

Comment: Are you comparing (`==`) or assigning (`=`)? Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: im trying to say if eg the department is Dublin then the bonus rate is 12

Comment: And do you do that with **assignment** operator or **equality** operator?

Comment: You should use some IDE if you're learning Java, to correct you for elementary mistakes like this. Google "Eclipse download" or "IntelliJ IDEA community download". Both are free to use.

Comment: The other day I've noticed a comment unders similar question that there is no day on SO without someone having problems with comparing strings in Java - looks like it is very true.

Comment: Ok so it should be the equality operator,thanks.

Comment: You should read a java tutorial or something instead of asking for help here, then ask here anything that you have trouble with. Comparing strings with `==` is an error in most cases (you should use `.equals`) and comparing anything with `=` is always an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (department="London")
```

should be

```
if ("London".equals(department))
```

Same goes for the `if(department ="Dublin")` statement

More info:

- [How do I compare Strings in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You would want to use this rather than the '==' operator other answers are suggesting. '==' checks the [equals()](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) method, which for Strings, checks both Strings location in memory to see if they are the exact same String.

Comment: I am aware of what `==` operator does. I believe the OP wants to compare content rather than references, so my answer stands. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not meaning to correct anything in your answer but actually agree with you and am adding the reason why he would want to use equals without having to click the link.

Comment: OK now I know what to do,sometimes its the simple logic that catches me as I have only started programming this September.Now,as a bonus, I also know the difference between "==" and ".equals()"

Answer (score 0):

You're using assignment operator `=` instead of equality `==`

Comment: Right, this is a common mistake.  But `==` won't work either, so this answer is somewhat misleading.

Comment: It will work as it's not comparing to `new String("Dublin")`, but interned one. Having said that, equals is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] cars = { " Lamborghini Diablo", "Ford Raptor", "Ferrari Testarossa", "Porsche 911 Carrera",
            "Jensen Interceptor", "Lamborghini Huracán", "Ferrari 812 Superfast", "Jeep Gladiator" };

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {

        if ("Jensen Interceptor".equals(cars[i])) {

            System.out.println("Dump Car");
        }

        System.out.println("Master Piece");

    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a little comment to explain your answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).